# Guice Singleton in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, guice

Are Google GUICE Singleton objects really singleton when used in a Google App engine context? If not how can I ensure true singleton behaviour?

Comment: Define your interpretation of "true singleton behavior": One instance per request, per Guice injector, per classloader, per JVM, per AppEngine app, ...? Also, what's the actual goal you want to achieve with this singleton?

Comment: One singleton per app engine application. I want to increment a value for each request. And keep it in the database.

Comment: Can you give more detail how the value would be incremented per request, e.g. do you want to count the number of requests across all frontend instances? Regardless, the solution will probably invole [memcached](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview) for read performance, Datastore for persistence and possibly [sharded counting](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) for write performance (if there's need for several increments/second).

Comment: Yes, It needs to count the number of requests in all front-end instances and I'm using memcache to reduce the number of read requests  sent to the Datastore. This value is being used by about 70% of the requests to the application. Sharded counting is a new concept for me. I will check that out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Guice singleton is a singleton only under the Guice injector it was created from. It's not a singleton in the JVM or by any other means. If you need concurrent processes to have a coherent view of some data, you should use a database or some other means of synchronization.